# Can not save data in subdirectory of Documents iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I want to create a subdirectory (Document/MyFolder) in iphone. I can create subdirectory but can not save data in subdirectory. Here is my code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS"];

 NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

 NSString *currentDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *tileImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",currentDate,@".png"];

 NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];

 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){

 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; 

 }

 NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tileImage);

 [data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];

 [dateFormat release];

 [date release];
```

How can save data in this subdirectory?

**Also I need to delete this folder when user clicks button. How can I delete this subdirectory (in this case MyFolder)?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dataPath` doesn't include `tileImageName`. You should define a `tileImagePath` to include the `tileImageName`. It should probably be,

```
 NSString * tileImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",currentDate,@".png"];
 NSString * dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
 NSString * tileImagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:tileImageName];

 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; 
 }

 NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tileImage);    
 [data writeToFile:tileImagePath atomically:YES];
```

So your `dataPath` is something like `../Documents/MyFolder` and not `../Documents/MyFolder/20110622_011700.png` as you intended.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I will do it. How can I delete the folder so that all the data is deleted from folder?

Comment: Use [`removeItemAtPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW21)